# Set active link (without ul list)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m searching about this but only find ul list based solutions.

I have this code:

```
<div class='nav'>
  <a class='nav-link nav-01' id="tab01" href='#scene-1'></a>
  <a class='nav-link nav-02' id="tab02" href='#scene-2'></a>
  <a class='nav-link nav-03' id="tab03" href='#scene-3'></a>
  <a class='nav-link nav-04' id="tab04" href='#scene-4'></a>
</div>
```

I would like to change class (for example "nav-01" to "nav-01-on") when click on it. Also, each link have an active class style different (nav-01-on for nav-01, nav-02-on for nav-02...).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, each link have an active class style different (nav-01-on for nav-01, nav-02-on for nav-02...).

Since you are working with classes you do not really need to have a different class name to describe the 'active' state of the links. That's the cool thing about CSS classes.

Since your links already have a unique identifier, in the form of the `id` attribute you have given them, you only need to apply a generic 'active state' class, such as `on` for example (could be whatever you want). Then in your CSS you could do something like

```
    .on {
        /* general rules for elements with the .on class */
    }

    #tab01.on {
        /* specific rules for element #tab01 with the .on class */
    }
```

> I would like to change class (for example "nav-01" to "nav-01-on") when click on it.

Since your question is tagged as `jquery` I will use jQuery, so here's a naive solution of what you want. You can improve on it, I am sure.

```
//We start assuming we have no active link
var $activeLink = null;

//We apply a listener to every element with the class .nav-link, using jQuery
$('.nav-link').click(function() {
    if ($activeLink) {
        $activeLink.removeClass('on');
    } 
    //Store the link we clicked on as the active link. 
    //Notice we are wrapping it with the jQuery function,
    //so $activeLink is a jQuery object
    $activeLink = $(this);
    $activeLink.addClass('on'); 
});
```

Here's a fiddle of the above: **https://jsfiddle.net/p1tumym9/4/**

Comment: You are welcome. If you found to be explanatory enough and it answered your question consider accepting it as an answer

Comment: Oh, you had already accepted another answer, hadn't seen that.

Comment: Sorry! I don't know about check the answer. Now your answer is checked as answer.

Comment: Only one question for finish, how can set active link by default (actually is "null"). Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, go ahead, do ask!

Comment: One way to do that would be to have already added the `on` (or however you decided to call it) class on the link element you want (e.g. `<a class='nav-link nav-01 on' id="tab01" href='#scene-1'></a>`) and then set `$activelink` to be `var $activeLink = $('.nav-link.on');`, which means the element which has both a `nav-link` and an `on` class

Comment: Fantastic!! It´s working well. Thanks again for your time. Have a great weekend! ;-)

Comment: You too mate! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Fiddle to play around with**](https://jsfiddle.net/smmp5nam/1/)

What you should do to make life a lot easier for yourself is to toggle between a single `active` class and in your CSS just specify how each of your links will look like when it has the `active` class, instead of creating a bunch of unique classes (which can get difficult to manage).

How to toggle between the active link:

```
$('.nav').find('a').click(function(){
  // Remove active class from all links
  $('.nav').find('a').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
  // Add active class to current link
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

And in your CSS just specify how each link will look when given the `active` class:

```
.nav-01.active {
  /* active styles for nav-01 */
}

.nav-02.active {
  /* active styles for nav-01 */
}

.nav-03.active {
  /* active styles for nav-01 */
}

.nav-04.active {
  /* active styles for nav-01 */
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'm going to test it ;-)